# bind: Permission denied (13) with stunnel for set https

Tags: ssl, https, fossil, stunnel

I am getting this error:

> [!] bind: Permission denied (13)
>   [!] Error binding service [https] to :::443

These are my stunnel.conf settings:

```
[https]
accept = 120.113.121.99:443
accept = :::443
key = /etc/stunnel/localhost.key
cert = /etc/stunnel/localhost.crt
exec = /usr/bin/fossil
execargs = /usr/bin/fossil http /home/kane/repository/2017wcm_g4.fossil -- https --nojail
```

Why is this error occurring? How would I best remedy it?

Comment: Please provide more information. What are you trying to do? What are you using to do whatever you are trying to do? What have you tried already to fix this error? It is entirely unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Attempted to fix grammar, make intent clearer.

Answer (score 6):

Two things come to mind:

1. Are you certain there's no other program listening to port 443? (`netstat --listen`)
2. Also, I know Linux requires root permissions in order to listen to ports below 1024. Does stunnel have those permissions?